# SQL Server: GPS Cordinates distance USING calculated column

Tags: sql-server, gps, calculated-columns

I have a table that I'm inserting GPS coordinates (lat/lon) on each record.

table schema is like: (Id, Time, Lat, Lon)

Is it possible to calculate distance of two continuous records using Calculated columns? 
Something that schema become like this: (Id, Time, Lat, Lon, Distanceof( ID -1, ID ))

Note:  I know how to calculate distance of two points, but I dont know if its possible to access multiple rows data on a calculated column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to directly use values of other rows in calculated column definition, but one can create a user-defined function and use it:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CalcDistance(@prev_row_id INT, @row_id INT)
AS 
  ...
```

and then define calculated column expression as `dbo.CalcDistance(Id - 1, Id)`.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a function Distanceof for calculating the distance. 
and you can select as

Select id, time, Lat,Lon, Distanceof(Lat, Lng,radius) from the table. 
it will calculate for each row. But it will timeconsuming if you are doing many rows